# Is there a Time-only R class?

Tags: r

Is there a way to store time data in R in a class that only handles time (without dates)? I don't need to include dates and I feel it will take up extra memory and visualization space. I am looking for a lean class that only handles times, something like this:

```
t1 = as.Time("10:38") 
t2 = as.Time("10:39")
t1-t2
```

There exists an `as.Date` function, but a time counterpart would be great. `POSIXct` stores too much information.

UPDATE: package `chron` requires extra work to add seconds, and time subtraction that results in negative values is no longer formatted as a time:

```
>t1 = times(paste0("10:38",":00"))
>t2 = times(paste0("10:39",":00"))
> t1-t2
[1] -0.0006944444   
> t2-t1
[1] 00:01:00
```

Comment: Short answer: No.    Longer answer:  Please research your question better.

Comment: There is the class `period` in the `lubridate` package.

Comment: Just in case, pay attention to lubridate package.

Comment: See `difftime` in base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `data.table` has a new class ITime which solves this problem ideally.

```
library(data.table)
> as.ITime("12:00")-as.ITime("11:10:01")
[1] "00:49:59"
```

Answer (score 4):

As my previous comment, here an example of `period` class from the `lubridate` package, which I think it might be useful for you. For more information just `?Period-class`.

```
library(lubridate)
t1 <- hm("10:38") 
t1
[1] "10H 38M 0S"
t2 <-  hm("10:39")
t1 - t2
[1] "-1M 0S"
```

Comment: Thanks, the `lubridate` package has what I need.