# Format in R with hours

Tags: r, time, lubridate

**Dears**,

I need the following time format in a column:

- 00:00
- 01:00
- 02:00
- ...
- 23:00

to after work with time series in R. **Please help me**

Comment: Just to put you on the right path. There is a R package called `lubridate` which has virtually all the tools needed for formatting time.

Comment: perhaps `data.table::as.ITime()`? Impossible to answer without actual sample data

Comment: [R does not have a time class per se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999070/is-there-a-time-only-r-class).  You could use `datetime`s, or perhaps `lubridate`'s `period` or `interval` classes might help, but without more information it's impossible to know what is best for you.  Dealing with times is more difficult than you might think.  Even apparently simple questions like "how many seconds are there in a minute?" are not easy to answer in the general case.